# gRPC not generating interface for a service, only a service class

Tags: java, grpc, protocol-buffers

I am new to gRPC and have this problem: I created a .proto with rpc service definition. After compilation I get generated sources: all messages have a class that implements an interface. However a service itself doesn't implement any interface - it's simply not generated. And that's the interface I'm supposed to implement in my server. What am I doing wrong? I am pretty sure gRPC documentation says nothing about this problem.

My .proto service:

```
syntax = "proto3";
option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "com.blah.my.rpc.api";
option java_outer_classname = "MyServiceProto";
option objc_class_prefix = "Pb";

package com.blah.my.rpc.api;

service MyService
{
  rpc connect(PbEmptyMessage) returns (PbParameterGroup){}

  rpc getParams(PbGenList) returns (PbParameterGroup){}

}

message PbEmptyMessage
{
}

message PbGenId
{
      string paramName = 1;
      string systemName = 2;
      string sName = 3;
      string sId = 4;
}

message PbParameterGroup
{
       bytes sParameters = 2;
       fixed64 time  = 3;
}
```

My plugin definition in maven:

```
<extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.0.Final</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.5.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.0-beta-2:exe:${os.detected.classifier}
                    </protocArtifact>
                    <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
                    <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:0.14.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</pluginArtifact>
                    <protoSourceRoot>${basedir}/src/main/resources</protoSourceRoot>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: I don't have a complete answer, but note that the "stubs" (service interfaces) are generated by a separate protoc plugin from the other code. It looks like you're naming the grpc plugin in your maven file but you may want to investigate whether it is not being invoked for some reason.

Answer (score 9):

Got the answer from plugin developer.

1st thing: goals should be:

```xml
<goal>compile</goal>
<goal>compile-custom</goal>
```

2d and main thing: `<outputDirectory>` is reused between the two goals and thus its contents are rewritten. Removing this parameter solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and resolve the problem which waste my 3+ hours time.
After add `compile-custom` to execution goals, service stub been generated finally.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, and @Alexandra's answer got me headed in the right direction.

`outputDirectory` is the parameter that needs to be removed. The GRPC generated code goes in a different package, but if you specify an `outputDirectory` parameter things will get overwritten.

I also found that I needed to specify an explicit path to `protoc` in my maven file. That said, I'm no maven on that build system.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.1</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <protocExecutable>/usr/local/bin/protoc</protocExecutable>
                <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
            </configuration>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>compile-custom</goal>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Using the above seems to have worked for me.